# CodeIgniter cache preventing AJAX calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, caching

I'm building my site in codeigniter. I'm making multiple ajax calls on one page, when the user is scrolling. My site is also cached with codeigniter. I seems that cache is preventing ajax calls.

It goes like this:
 *I refresh my site and after the user scrolls it makes the first ajax call. There should be several ajax calls after that, but they don't execute(don't know why). Then I delete my cache, go back to the site and scroll. Again only the first ajax call is executed.*

So my best guess is that **cache is somehow preventing the calls**, but I don't know how to bypass the problem.

I'm relatively new to ajax and codeigniter. I googled it, but nothing useful comes up. I was hoping you guys might be able to help me :)

Comment: did  you see your console to see what if there is any error ?

Comment: or could you please put some of your code ?

Comment: As @allamjaddou mentioned, please post your ajax-related code and check the console for errors - if you are requesting data from the same location multiple times, it is possible that the request is being cached, which could be resolved by appending a time stamp to the request url

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are making an ajax call to:

*www.yoursite.com/some_class_to_cache/some_function/some_parameter*

The problem is that the router respons with the cached page

*www.yoursite.com/some_class_to_cache/some_function/cached_parameter*

So the response you are recieving is this cached page and not the ajax response.
To change this behavior one solution is to create an ajax call handler located somewhere else that is not cached.

***www.yoursite.com/some_ajax_class/some_function/some_parameter***

and from there create the **some_class_to_cache** object and call the **some_function** with **some_parameter**.

Answer (score 0):

`jquery` had a solution but `codeigniter` returns a 404 page

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

from what I can see the problem is jquery uses what they call a cache buster with 
`_?=xxx` for the get value, if I could find a away to make the url work with

that should solve the problem easier

```
www.yoursite.com/some_class_to_cache/some_function/some_p
    arameter?_=1469969058680
```

this is what fixed it for me

change config.php to this

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```